# How can I understand what is the method performed when an API implemented in Django is called?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am absolutly not a Python developer (I am a Java dev) but I have to do some minor change on a Python projcet based on **Django** framework and I am finding some difficulties trying to understand how it works.

Basically I have to do a change into an API that have the following endpoint:

```
https://MY-PROJECT-NAME-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1/accounts:accounts/
```

(I retrireved it analyzing te call made by a web application using the Chrome DevTool Network tab)

Coming from Java Spring framework I am pretty sure that also **DJango** should map this endpoint to a method that implement my API logic, is it?

How can I retrieve this method? (I need to understand what method is performed when this call happens).

Another doubt is: I think that this is the endpoint URL:

```
https://MY-PROJECT-NAME-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1/accounts
```

but what is this **:accounts/** appended at the end of the URL?

Thank you

**EDIT-1**: Into the **urls.py** file I only have these line:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from ressource.views import *

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^connexion/', connexion,name="connexion"),
 ]
```

Comment: try to search inside your u`urls.py` files something like `):(?P` maybe someone create an url patterns with colon.

Comment: @BearBrown I added an edit at the end of my original post wit the content of my urls.py file

Comment: Your question is unclear. Of course, if you want to use that URL in your app, you need to define it in your urls.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url) need at least two argument, a regex pattern (`r'^connexion/'`) and a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view). The view is the method called. In this case it's `connection`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a GET method of lists of accounts or both GET and POST method together or even just a POST method depending on how the views was configured